# Skin effect and currents

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

Here in this picture

[image: http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Skineffect_reason.svg&filetimestamp=20080727190721]

you can see $I_W$ which is induced by H.
But why $I_W$ is not vice versa?
Because of
$$rot \, \vec B = \mu_0 \, \left( \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} + \vec j \right)$$ ?
Maybe I have to use
$$\oint \vec{E}\cdot \, d\vec{r} = - \int \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}\cdot \, d\vec{A} = U_{induced}$$

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you are asking. Do you want to know why the current is induced by the H field, rather than the H field being induced by the current Iw ?

Comment: @Colin K Hi! I want to know where Iw comes from?

Comment: The eddy currents are determined by the second equation you listed.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Because dB/dt in the Iw-Area will increase, there must be a E-field which goes anti-clockwise. (How can I mark the solution?)

Comment: @kame: Write your solution as an answer and then mark it as the accepted solution.  You can answer your own questions.